# Static friction force increases or decreases with increase in inclination until impending of motion?

Tags: forces, friction

Consider a block of weight *W* lying on the horizontal board.

As in the case when $\theta=0$  and we apply force parallel to board, friction force will increase until the impending of motion and equals to *μN*.

Does friction force *f*<sub>s</sub> increases also when inclined at some angle? 
I think *f*<sub>s</sub>, the static friction force decrease because when the board is inclined Normal force becomes  *N=W $\cos\theta$*, normal force decreases with increase in  $\theta$.

Am I thinking  right? If not then explain. 

Or If I am right then it should be written in books that friction force decreases  with inclination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the maximum static frictional force is $\mu\, N$.

If the board is horizontal no frictional force is necessary to keep the block stationary.

Inclining the board will require there to be a static frictional force acting on the block equal in magnitude but opposite in direction to the component of the weight down the slope $mg\sin \theta$.

As $\theta$ increase so the static frictional force increases.

This continues until the angle of the board is such that the maximum static frictional force $\mu mg\cos \theta$ is equal to the component of the weight of the block down the slope $mg\sin \theta$.

So $\mu = \tan \theta$ and this the basis of a method for finding the coefficient of static friction.

You are correct in saying that the **maximum** possible static frictional force $\mu mg \cos \theta$ decreases with increasing board angle.

Comment: I meant increase so it should read "The **actual** static friction force increases but it it less than the **maximum** static force which decreases as the angle increases.".